# access parent method parameters from inner class anonymous constructor when names are same

Tags: java

I have a method, inside I create instance of an other object by  anonymous inner class and do some initialization  in its anonymous constructor ,inside the constructor If I want  to access parent Object if it was a class I can do it by ClassName.this  etc  but in this case how can I access the parent instance which is a method with its name?
Here is an example of the problem I face , I have to rename the methods or fields  in case both parent and innerclass have the same  name.

```
public static void test(final String param1){
    new InnerClass(){
        {
            this.param1=param1;
        }
    }.doSomething();;
}

public static class InnerClass {
    String param1;
    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("param1 "+param1);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is horrible. Just horrible. Even if you could hack your way around this why would you want to? Why not take `param1` in the ctor? Otherwise rename the method parameter. But using an instance initialiser on an anonymous class to hack internal state is just nasty.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass a parameter to the `InnerClass` constructor, instead of using an anonymous subclass:

```
public static void test(final String param1){
    new InnerClass(param1).doSomething();
}

public static class InnerClass {
    String param1;

    public InnerClass(String param1) {
        this.param1 = param1;
    }

    void doSomething(){
        System.out.println("param1 "+param1);
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to access parent   which is method in this case ?

Comment: No, it can't access local variables in the calling method.  Just pass in the values you need as constructor parameters.